# Java tld tag in title

Tags: java, jsp

I use tld tag, and I use it:

```
<myTag:title objectId="id1"></myTag:title>
```

and it is ok.

I have code:

```
<div class="myClass" title="TITLE"><jsp:text /></div>
```

I want use myTag instead of TITLE, how can I do that? Function of myTag return only value, not html code.